# How to update multiple model objects at a time with bulk_update?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Here from the frontend user gives the input values like this ['1','2', '3']. I want to update the multiple objects at time with `bulk_update` and I tried like this but this is giving me this error.

`ValueError: All bulk_update() objects must have a primary key set.`

With this similar way I created objects with `bulk_create` method which worked fine but with `bulk_update` it is not workin.

**Here I want to update multiple model objects with different values at a time ?**

```
class PVariant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....

#views

quantity = request.POST.getlist('quantity')
#['1','2','3']
names = request.POST.getlist('names')
fields = ['name', 'price', 'quantity'..]
params = zip(names, quantity, weight,..)
variants = [PVariant(name=param[0],sku=param[1], quantity=param[2], weight=param[3],
                                       product=product) for param in params]
PVariant.objects.bulk_update(variants, fields)
```

**EDIT:**
From the client side I am getting this types of data in the view.

```
['name1', 'name2'] names
['12', '1213.0'] field1
['12.0', '12.0']  field2
['1244', '1244']  field3
['11', '11']   field4
['12.0', '12.0'] field5
```

Comment: What parameter are you indexing on, sku? You need to have data indexed by unique identifier included in request to determine which rows require which updates.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer based on additional information provided in your question

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

This can be achieved in two queries regardless of number of variants that need to be updated.

You just need to index your data properly on client side so that you can determine which updates to apply to which field server-side.

```
pvs = PVariant.objects.filter(id__in=pvs_indexed_by_id.keys())

for pv in pvs:
    data = pvs_indexed_by_id[pv.id]
    
    pv.name = data[“name”]
    ...

PVariant.objects.bulk_update(pvs, [“name”, ...])
```

If you are unable to modify the data shape client side simply clean up the data prior to the code above:

```
fields = (“name”, “field1”, ...)

data = {}

for i, field enumerate(request.POST):
    data[fields[i]] = field[i]
```

Comment: Isn't  there any solution with nested for loops? i want to handle it on the views as possible.

Comment: @D_P what would you want to do with nested for loops? It’s not necessary. You need to modify the data shape of the form on client side to submit a hash rather than an array. An array is the incorrect data type to use for this problem. However, if you were forced to use arrays you would have to preprocess form in your view to modify data shape from array to hash. You could do this by creating a hash separate hash table of index: field_name (ie: 0: “name”) then instead of pv.name = data[“name”] you would do pv.getattr(index_to_field_map[i]) = data[i] where i is index from for loop.

Comment: @D_P the examples I provided would be appropriate in the view or model. Most of your business logic should be in models for ease in maintenance and unit testing, but depending on complexity of your application and concerns about maintenance you can get away with just putting it in a view.

Comment: @D_P in either case there is no need to nest loops at most you would have two for loops, but ideally you would use correct data types for the problem and only need one loop.

Comment: Yes i think the problem is because of the data type array and nested loops but I can't change that from the client side now so I am using array.

Comment: Can you give the solution with this data type array also ?

Comment: @D_P what is the full payload provided by the client?

Comment: `id_to_field_map = {0: “name”..}` how can I make this dynamic since the list is dynamic ?

Comment: @D_P there’s no way to make this dynamic since you need to map data that doesn’t have a reference to a field and your field doesn’t have a reference to the index provided by client, this has to be manually mapped. Furthermore, you need some sort of unique identifier to be able to update a record in the db—I’m not seeing that information in the updated question.

Comment: @D_P you could make it a tulle and ensure that fields are ordered correctly

Comment: I converted all the fields from client side in to tuple  like this `fields=('name1','name2','1','2'..)` and now  i got this error `IndexError: string index out of range` with this line `data[fields[i]] = field[i]`

Answer (score -2):

All `PVariant` objects should be saved first (call `save` method) before update.
Something like:

```
variants = []
for param in params:
   inst = PVariant(display_name=param[0],sku=param[1], quantity=param[2], weight=param[3], product=product)
   inst.save()
   variants.append(inst)
```

Comment: doesn't this create a new one instead of updating ?

Comment: No. Try in Django shell to create `PVariant` object as you did in your code and then, without calling `save`, print it's `id` - it will be `None` because object wasn't actually stored in DB yet. This is used when you need to initiate record with some data and then make some dependant modification before actually saving it.

Comment: Isn't there any solutions with `bulk_update` since with similar process `bulk_create` was working fine

Comment: It's creating a new object but does it saves it to DB? Does object have `id` assigned? No other options is possible with `bulk_update` because instead of `bulk_create` it needs to have already stored records to perform update.

Comment: Avoid creating one by one in a loop as this ends up being an n+1 problem.